# Updating Saved Data in Parse iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform, insert-update

I use this code to update my data on data browser on parse.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserInformation"];

[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"dIwnk9tbr0" block:^(PFObject *gameScore, NSError *error)
{
    gameScore[@"email_address"] = @"testkolang@y.com";
    [gameScore saveInBackground];

}];
```

But I have this kind of error. And the data on parse is not changed.

```
2014-03-12 18:08:06.036 AndroidiOsPushTest[3725:1803] Error: object not found for update (Code: 101, Version: 1.2.18)
```

Comment: Try logging out the NSError from the block. And check the Parse database if the object has the same ID and the class name is the same.

Comment: it is the same in the database.

Answer (score 1):

```
    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:objectID block:^(PFObject *UserInfo, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {

           [UserInfo setObject:self.userName.text forKey:@"username"];
           [UserInfo setObject:@"US" forKey:@"country"];

            [UserInfo saveInBackground];
        }
        else {
            // Did not find any UserStats for the current user
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }
   }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue looks like the one in : [I can not update a record in Parse; Error: "object not found for update (Code: 101, Version: 1.2.16)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190264/i-can-not-update-a-record-in-parse-error-object-not-found-for-update-code-1/22192018#22192018)

Error code 101 in Parse means :

> 101: Object doesn't exist, or has an incorrect password.

First, you should check if your object exists and if the error is not null.
Then, if these steps are successful, you should check for the ACL of the object : if you don't have permissions to edit it, you will be unable to save it and get the error 101.

Comment: i have this ACL something on my table, but it does not update any.

Answer (score 0):

It relate to ACL, please check your dashboard for the data column "ACL"

The write should lock on specific user ID. you need change it from your dashboard to update its permission to

```
{"*":{"write":true,"read":true}}
```

You can check more detail on my reply in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24530547/saving-user-causes-object-not-found-error/24694142#24694142)

Answer (score 0):

From Parse.com (Hector Ramos)

```
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserStats"];
[query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject * userStats, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
    // Found UserStats
    [userStats setObject:newScore forKey:@"latestScore"];

    // Save
    [userStats saveInBackground];
  } else {
    // Did not find any UserStats for the current user
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
  }
}];
```