# Big issue - Parse object cannot point to another class's object that has an ACL of public read only?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, acl

Let me explain this with an example, say there are 2 classes, Class 1 and Class 2. Class 1 has all of its objects as Public read only. I now want to create a pointer in Class 2 object that points to Class 1. Unfortunately this is not possible with parse.com it looks like since when I try to do this it complains with an exception :

```
[Error]: object not found for update (Code: 101, Version: 1.6.2)
```

Is this a bug or is this how the ACL security works. I could not find any documentation about this. Could any one from parse help me answer this question. Fast response highly appreciated.

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348092/updating-saved-data-in-parse-ios, May be u ll get some idea from this.

Comment: I am not updating the object that is read only, I am just adding a pointer to this read only object in another object. Apparently Parse does not allow this. Is this a bug? If not where is this documented?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

A hack around it is instead of storing a pointer to Class 1 in Class2, instead make a field on Class2 that is an NSString.  This string stores the objectId string of Class1.  Then when you query, search for Class1.objectId (which is an NSString) instead of Class1.  You lose the link in the Parse web gui, but gain the functionality you need without having to make Class1 public write access.

I've heard this can be solved by using Cloud Code and a master key, but I personally don't know how to do it.