# Parse, updating PFObject from iOS client when object was created by another user?

Tags: parse-platform

I am having trouble saving an object in parse from my iOS client.

Flow:

User A saves PFObject form iOS client, User B retrieves PFObject and wants to update it, 
when user B tries to save the changes made to the PFObject I get this error:

```
object not found for update (Code: 101, Version: 1.2.19)
```

So, to my understanding this is because the only user that had write access to the PFObject was user A since it was the one that actually created it.

Question is:

how can I grant B write access to that same PFObject that A created in the first place?

Can it be done from the client?

If not, what kind of **cloud function** can I write to alter the ACL on the PFObject so that B can then update the PFObject? Can I do it in before save?

Here's the code:

```
PFQuery * photoQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserPhoto"];
[photoQuery whereKey:@"username" equalTo:user.username];
[photoQuery whereKey:@"version" equalTo:version];
NSArray * photos = [photoQuery findObjects];

PFObject * photo = nil;
if([photos count]) {
    photo = [photos lastObject];
    NSNumber * previousVersion = [photo objectForKey:@"version"];
    [photo setObject:previousVersion?@(previousVersion.integerValue+1):@0 forKey:@"version"];
} else {
    photo = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"UserPhoto"];
    [photo setObject:version forKey:@"version"];
}

[photo setObject:user.username forKeyedSubscript:@"username"];
[photo removeObjectForKey:@"userRelation"];

PFACL * postACL = [PFACL ACLWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]];
[postACL setPublicReadAccess:YES];
[postACL setPublicWriteAccess:YES];
photo.ACL = postACL;

NSError * error;
BOOL savedPhoto = [photo save:&error];
```

Comment: Could u share your code for search and update by User B ?? Also you could have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190264/i-can-not-update-a-record-in-parse-error-object-not-found-for-update-code-1)

Comment: @walle84: I added the code in the question...

Comment: Did you check out that link which I shared and also move your PFACL code before you update it. As in your current scenario your updating and then later setting permission YES.

Comment: Here is a detailed answer on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24530547/saving-user-causes-object-not-found-error/24694142#24694142) might be helpful.

Comment: @walle84: I moved the ACL to before the update. Does not work.

Comment: what about the link that I provided u? Did it help out? Else I don't have much hands on ACL but still will search and if find out any thing then let u know.

Comment: Link didn't really help. Sorry.

Comment: The issue is basically very simple: unless the other user is added to the object's ACL with explicit read and write permissions, it just won't work. You have to know the related users while you are saving the object, to enable proper ACL.

Something akin to, within a broader method that created an array of users:
`for (PFUser *user in users) {
        PFACL *yourObjectACL = [PFACL ACL];
        [yourObjectACL setReadAccess:YES forUser:user];
        [yourObjectACL setWriteAccess:YES forUser:user];
    }`