# Swift 3 How to increment value in parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I created an app that has a forum and in that forum users can like a post.
When i try to increment the number of likes in parse it seems to increment it because when i print out the value, it prints correctly, but when i refresh parse, it stays at 0.

Here is my likeButton function:

```
    //This gives me the index of the cell in which the like button was tapped
    @IBAction func likeButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let buttonRow = (sender.tag)!


    let query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
    query.whereKey("body", equalTo: messages[buttonRow])
    query.whereKey("title", equalTo: titles[buttonRow])


    query.findObjectsInBackground { (object, error) in

        if error != nil {

            print(error)

        }else{

            if let post = object {
                for objects in post {
                    if let posts = objects as? PFObject {

                        //I would think this line is the only thing I'd need to execute but it isn't working
                        posts.incrementKey("Like", byAmount: 1)
                        let pre = [posts["Like"]!]

                        //this prints 1 --> meaning it worked
                        print(pre[0])
                        //This next line should update posts["Like"] but it doesn't
                        posts["Like"] = pre[0]
                        posts.saveInBackground()
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }

}
```

It seems like i'm incrementing it, but it is not saving. Please, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I think you only need one line `posts.incrementKey("Like", byAmount: 1)` and then you should use  `saveInBackground` with callback to check whether your save is successful or not

Comment: @3stud1ant3 can you show me how to do the saveInBackground with a callback. I tried doing just:     posts.incrementKey("Like", byAmount: 1) with     saveInBackground() but that didn't work

Comment: I guess you can do this: `posts.saveInBackground { (savedSuccessfully:Bool, error:Error?) -> Void in
        if savedSuccessfully {
            print("savedSuccessfully")
        } else {
            print(error)
        }
    }` , see what it prints,

Comment: @3stud1ant3 This is what I got as my error:                                                        Optional(Error Domain=Parse Code=101 "Object not found." UserInfo={code=101, temporary=0, error=Object not found., NSLocalizedDescription=Object not found.})

Comment: I don't understand, I think it can find the Like column because it does actually do the increment by 1. I know this because I print the value before and after it increments it.

Comment: Are you calling saveInBackground in your code elsewhere and are they working fine besides this?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 Does it have to do with the fact that when i print posts["Like"] that it returns an optional value: EX//: [Optional(1)]. And yes, I am calling the saveInBackground elsewhere it seems to work fine.

Comment: I dont think thats the problem because when you get a value from a dictionary in swift , it always returns an optional, here your save is not working, so we have to recitify that, please tell that are you using saveInbackground elsewhere in your code

Comment: @3stud1ant3 I use saveInBackground() without a block when a user follows another user.

Comment: is it working fine?

Comment: @3stud1ant3 Yes, it works just fine.

Comment: try this link and go through each answer, I think and hope you will find the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190264/i-can-not-update-a-record-in-parse-error-object-not-found-for-update-code-1

Comment: @3stud1ant3 thank you, the first answer on that forum solved my problem!

Comment: No worries, glad I could help